# newDiscord is not defined

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, discord.js, node-modules

so I've coded a discord bot in *Visual Studio Code*. It has worked perfectly fine before, but after reinstalling ***VSC***, it seems to not work anymore. Everytime i try to run the bot "**node .**", it gives me a "**newDiscord is not defined**". A screenshot of the error => **https://i.stack.imgur.com/tJQjI.jpg**. The top of my codes => **https://i.stack.imgur.com/vPMrX.jpg**

Comment: just space out `newDiscord` to `new Discord`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

newDiscord isn't a thing... What you can do is

```
new Discord.Client
```